# This error keeps popping up in my visual studio - RevocationStatusUnknown

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, visual-studio-2015

Here is the full error:
I just finished publishing a web service in VS2015 to my localhost the publised web service is working fine but then after awhile this error keeps popping up. what should i do to fix this? is there anything i should do to prevent this error in the future? Thank you.
**RevocationStatusUnknown -The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate**

[Error Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0Y49.png)

Comment: HTTPS corporate proxies can cause this because the certs are generated on the fly - if the proxies are already filtering revoked certs, then you can just use the solution below

Answer (score 10):

I have been getting the same error...in the end I simply turned off "Check for server certificate revocation *" in Internet Explorer settings

[image]